# Unexpected error while creating an installable trigger for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create an installable trigger for googlesheets and here is the Apps Script code that creates it:

```
function setTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log('x');
}
```

When I run the function `setTrigger()` from Apps Script, I get the exception:

```
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property forSpreadsheet on object ScriptApp.TriggerBuilder.setTrigger
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The issue is you are executing this script from a [standalone](http://function%20setTrigger()%20%7B%20%20%20var%20ss%20=%20SpreadsheetApp.openById(%27Spreadsheet_ID%27);%20%20%20ScriptApp.newTrigger(%22myFunction%22).forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();%20%7D%20%20function%20myFunction()%20%7B%20%20%20Logger.log(%27x%27);%20%7D) script.

In this case, there is not active spreadsheet and therefore you need to change:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
```

to:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet_ID');
```

where `'Spreadsheet_ID'` is the id of your spreadsheet file*.

Another option would be to go the target spreadsheet file and use your current solution. To do that, open `Tools => Script editor` and your script will be [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to the spreadsheet file.

### Solution:

```
function setTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet_ID');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
}

function myFunction() {
  Logger.log('x');
}
```

> *For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL
> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is
> "abc1234567".